# Question about compiling Sound Driver

Tags: gcc, make

Im trying to configure, complile audio drivers- lsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8

I get this error.

```
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-72-generic SUBDIRS=/home/mike/Downloads/0002-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa  CPP="gcc -E" CC="gcc" modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-72-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:217: archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-72-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:167: compile] Error 2
root@ubuntu:/home/mike/Downloads/0002-LinuxPkg_5.18rc8/Rt-Linux-HDaudio-5.18/alsa-driver-RTv5.18rc8/alsa-driver-RTv5.18/alsa#
```

Need your help! If you need more information, please let me know.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Regards,
Miguel

Comment: Please give us the link to the driver version you downloaded. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/pc-audio-codecs-high-definition-audio-codecs-software 

 Linux driver (3.0)
It only support kernel version under 3.18.
If it couldn't compile successfully, please upgrate your kernel.
New driver was keep update to kernel upstream(www.kernel.org).
5.18rc8